# Moving data between to databases with minor changes

Tags: django, django-models

Here's what I want to do: I need to migrate some models to another database modifying some of its attributes. The approach I came with was set another database setting in my DATABASES settings named 'production'.
Then I do this:

```
for cat_to, cat_from in category_names.items():
    c_f = InRadarCategory.objects.get(name=cat_from)
    c_t = InRadarCategory.objects.get(name=cat_to)

    for ad in InRadarAd.objects.filter(category=c_f):
        ad.pk = None
        ad.category = InRadarCategory.objects.using('production').get(name=c_t.name)
        ad.save(using='production')
```

Note that, before saving it to the other database, I modify it's category attribute with an object that's in the other database. After that, I try to push it in by calling save on `ad` instance, but using the production database.

That gives me the error:

```
instance is on database "default", value is on database "production"
```

Django docs states [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases) that:

*Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases. If you have used a router to partition models to different databases, any foreign key and many-to-many relationships defined by those models must be internal to a single database.*

Question is: Am I at the right path but missing something silly? Is there a alternative approach to achieve this?

Comment: Are you just going to run this script in a shell? If so, then why not just do the migration in SQL?

Comment: I created a django command(i.e. shell) to do this. I think by using sql would have to handle cross joins, multiple inserts, multiple selects, multiple databases, etc. And that's why Django ORM is here: to keep things simple with my models and the relation of those. Well, I'll just reinvent the wheel doing it that way.

Comment: I don't think you can have a model with the same name in each of the databases. What you'd need to do is declare a renamed InRadarAd model routed to another database. And just then recreate instances one by one.

Comment: @pythonishvili Well, I think models are just a way to represent data on mysql. I don't see any problems with having the same representation of data on two databases. Don't you agree?

Comment: OK, I just don't think Django ORM can stand having two models with the same name.